# how to handle significant changes to my answer?

Tags: discussion

A few people have been making significant changes to my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4192849/revisions

I contacted the original editor offline and suggested that they add a new answer with all the amendations and I would like to it for people that wanted it. I feel like adding all the extra details, while might help some people, take away from the simpleness of the answer.

how should I address this?  Should I just revert it when they change it?  Is there a way to lock my answer so others can only suggest improvements but not edit?

I'm also curious what people think about my stance on this - is it right for me to insist that my minimal answer stay minimal?

Comment: People were trying to help you improve the post. In my opinion, a post with *just code in it* is not an answer. It doesn't do anything to help people understand why your answer is helpful to anyone a similar answer.

Comment: You are free to roll back the change, but I think you are missing the point of the edits; a sparse and concise answer is fine, but *just code* is not helpful.

Comment: wait.... you contacted someone OFFLINE? for an edit? isn't that overkill?

Comment: and I'm with Martijn on that one.... there's already way too many "copy paste" coders around that never really understand what they do. Providing "minimal" answers (code-only in that case) only helps that. The OP never understands WHY he does it or why it works.... they just copy, paste, move on, until the next error where they copy, paste, move on.

Comment: With the post clearly being referenced a lot to have garnered that many upvotes over time, I think your post is better of with some explanation. Including comments that clarify your post into your answer is quite helpful. Try to meet the editors half-way instead, and find a way to incorporate some of the feedback in your own words.

Comment: @MartijnPieters That doesn't make it appropriate for them to basically re-write the answer themselves.  Personally I think that what they wrote is much better than what the OP has, but they should have *posted a new answer* with that content, not editing their own answer into someone else's.

Comment: @Servy: yes, the edits are more substantive that I'd have made. But I can see why they were made.

Comment: It's not like people were adding content that they just pulled out of thin air;  the notes for the March 10 revision says "Migrate all the useful info from the comments."  Code dumps that don't do anything to explain the code aren't helpful, and as SO employees and moderators love to point out, comments aren't permanent and can be deleted at any time.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables If they were migrating *the OP's comments* to the answer, that'd be fine.  They weren't though, they were migrating other people's comments to the answer.  You can't just write a comment to an answer with new content, and then use that as the basis for editing it into the answer.

Comment: I'm curious about the critical reception of the question. This seems standard "not a fat chance in hell" that those edits should have been made. None of the answers on that question have other than idle patter + code. Hardly different from many, many answers I see. I prefer explanations in answers, but would never stuff my own views into someone else's answer. Fix a typo, yes. Add something from a comment by the actual poster, yes. Make things up? No.

Comment: @Patrice  - I wanted to explain to him why I reverted his changes.  I said I appreciated his additions but they they weren't my words - I wouldn't add so much detail, and I think even adding extra detail can take away from the answer.  Additionally, I told him that if he wanted to add his own answer with the additional detail, I would be happy to edit my answer with a link saying that this other answer goes into more detail, etc, etc.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - before these edits were made, my answer had 20 times the upvotes of the next nearest answer. So I think the answer is helpful for other people with similar problems. The real "aha" part of my answer was that you could specify a table after the `DELETE` almost everything that was added outside of that is just commentary. The only novelty is that you can't use LIMIT or ORDER BY - but those don't relate to the question.

Comment: Also - can anyone explain why this has such so many negative votes?  It's a bad question?

Comment: @Yehosef: and a short explanation *saying* that added would have netted you 40 times the votes perhaps.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - perhaps - but that's speculation and I'm not trying to craft my answers to score the upvotes.  The point is that it's very helpful for people without any extra explanation.  I disagree with the idea that all the valuable comments should be integrated into the answer. If someone thinks the extra comments are useful, they should post an alternative answer integrating the comments from my or other answers.

Comment: update for anyone interested - since the editor posted his alternative answer, my answer has continued to get upvotes (around 12) whereas the alternative answer has not gotten any.  His answer is before mine so people searching via google will see his answer first, and I link to his answer in mine.   While it's probable that people will upvote mine because it already has so many upvotes, it is interesting that people are not interacting with his answer.  It is at least anecdotal evidence that sometimes "less is more" when it comes to an answer.

Comment: @Yehosef No. That isn't evidence of anything at all.

Comment: @Patrice, You misread that... (or he miswrote that). Either way, he contacted me [via SE comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/652770/delete-with-join-in-mysql/4192849#comment46539037_4192849), not offline.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If someone makes radical changes to your question that change the content of it in ways that you don't like, you can roll it back.  If users continue to edit the post, flag for moderator attention; they can lock the post if they want.

As much as I feel that their edits make the answer better, fundamentally they're just editing their own answer into your post, and that's not appropriate.  Edits are there to improve the presentation of the answer, not to radically change its content.  They should have posted their own answer with that content, or had *you* edit it into your own post (which, for the record, I encourage you to do, even if you choose to do it in your own words).

Comment: Thanks for your comment/suggestions.  As I said in one of the comments on this question, I suggested to the original editor to post a new answer with all his compilation and I would link to it in my question.  Would that be appropriate?

Comment: Edits are there for improvement. Full stop. If, as you say, the edits make the answer better, the edits should stay in. This site cares about the quality of an answer, not who wrote it.

Comment: @Shane That's just strictly false.  The site's editing guidelines make that quite clear.

Comment: @Shane - for the record, I think the more verbose answer is not better - or I would have changed the answer.  I'm not refusing the edit for some pedantic reason - The person had a query that wasn't doing what they wanted - so I succinctly showed them how to get what they wanted. I don't think that adding a bunch of "fluff" text to hold people's hand through understanding how SQL works is needed.  But I respect other's style and I encouraged the original editor to add his answer as an alternative.

Comment: @Servy http://stackoverflow.com/tour -- "Our goal is to have the *best answers* to every question, so if you see questions or answers that can be improved, you can *edit* them."

Comment: @Shane The fact that SO's tour says that editing is a feature in no way states that you can edit anything about a post that you want, for any reason, and that there are no editing guidelines.  If you actually continue to read through the help center and look at the more intricate descriptions of how editing works on the site, you'd see that you *cannot* just put whatever content you want into someone else's answer.

Comment: @Servy http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing -- Edits are expected to be substantial and to leave the post better than you found it. Common reasons for edits include:

1 - To fix grammar and spelling mistakes
2 - To clarify the meaning of the post (without changing that meaning)
3 - To include additional information only found in comments, so all of the information relevant to the post is contained in one place
 4- To correct minor mistakes or add updates as the post ages
 5- To add related resources or hyperlinks

Comment: #3 is the most important one here. It says editing exists for the EXACT REASON the OP is complaining about.

Comment: @Yehosef *YOU* don't think. Clearly other people disagree. LIterally *everyone* who has commented on it disagrees. Even this answer disagrees that the short answer is better than the long one.

Comment: @Shane So you just completely skipped over the statement `To clarify the meaning of the post (without changing that meaning)`  that's *explicitly* stating that you should not be changing the meaning of the post, which you're actively encouraging.  The third point is there to reference content that the author has posted in comments, or acknowledged as changes they feel would be appropriate.  That someone has posted a comment that the author disagrees with doesn't mean that content can be edited into the answer.

Comment: @Shane And the correct way to express that disagreement over the quality of the answer *is to vote on it*.  (As well as to comment or post your own answer.)  Editing it into a different answer isn't the proper way to go about it.  How would you feel if you posted a detailed answer and Yehosef removed everything but the code because he sincerely felt that it improved the answer?

Comment: @Servy, I didn't "skip over it". It is irrelevant. There is a list of various reason why you would edit the post. Those are ORs not ANDs there. Try re-reading #3 again. It says nothing of where the information comes from. Just that you should edit answers to bring useful information from the comments into the answer. Full stop.

Comment: @Shane The editing guidelines specifically saying that you're not allowed to edit a post to change the content of the answer is irrelevant to your assertion that it's okay to completely edit the content of another person's answer?  You're serious?  The fact that a short summary of the features lacks some of the nuance is unfortunate; I do wish that those guidelines would be better clarified, but the fact remains that it's simply not appropriate to edit your own original answer into someone else's post.

Comment: @Servy The fact that you have to use the exact opposite of what is going on as an example shows how wrong you are. Because everyone is saying that in this case 'more is better'. How would I feel if someone came along and added to my answer and every else agrees that the added info improves the answer? I'd be grateful.

Comment: @Servy No one "edited their own original answer into someone else's post". What happened was people "included additional information only found in comments, so all of the information relevant to the post is contained in one place". ***all of the information relevant to the post is contained in one place*** That's the key phrase here. What the OP ended up doing was create a second answer with the extra useful information and linked to it from the first answer. That is NOT "all in one place" Yes it is irrelevant. Do you understand what "OR" means?

Comment: @Shane More is not better.  Everyone is *not* saying that.  People have said that the OP's original answer was lacking information, and that this specific edit added valuable information.  That in no way implies that more is always better.  Adding incorrect information isn't helpful; adding off topic information isn't helpful, adding  new information in a confusing or misleading way isn't helpful; adding content that's inappropriate or not phrased constructively isn't helpful.  If someone filled an answer of yours with hate speech would you be okay with it because it's adding content?

Comment: @Servy Also, extra information *doesn't* change the meaning. It is just extra.

Comment: @Servy Wow, that's a weak strawman. Try reading what I wrote next time. Let me repeat myself: Because everyone is saying that ***IN THIS CASE*** 'more is better'.

Comment: @Shane The fact that other people stated their own original content in comment doesn't mean that editing them into the post isn't them adding their own original content.  The OP also *didn't* create a second answer, other people that felt that his answer was lacking posted additional answers; he felt that his original answer was sufficient.

Comment: @Shane Adding additional information *Absolutely* changes the meaning and content of the post.

Comment: @Shane No, more is not *absolutely* better, even in this case.  There are all sorts of things that could be added that would make the answer worse.  That people have stated that this one edit contains useful information for this one answer in no way implies that all edits to this answer that add content would make it better.  I have no idea why you'd think that would be the case.

Comment: @Servy *I don't* think that is the case. Stop building strawmen. When I say "IN THIS CASE" I mean "IN THIS CASE" not some "hypothetical edits that never happened". No, it really doesn't change the meaning of the post. Go look at what we are talking about. Go look at the revisions. All of the other information does not change the short code snippet. The meaning: "This is the code you need to use" remains the same with the added information. The meaning is not changed. With the edit the post becomes "This is the code you need to use and this is *why*".

Comment: @Servy  And AGAIN reread #3. Reread the site tour. Where the content came from DOES NOT MATTER. What matters to the exchange is that "Our goal is to have the ***best answers*** to every question, so if you see questions or answers that can be improved, you can ***edit*** them." If the edits make the answer better, the edits should stay in. Period. Full Stop. Do not pass Go, Do no collect $200. The only thing that matters is whether or not the edits improve the question, and they do.

Comment: @Servy We should probably continue this in chat.

Comment: @Shane So you're saying that all of the editing guidelines posted in the help center mean nothing at all, because edits can do whatever they want and there are no guidelines on what they can and can't edit?  Sorry, but no.  You are mis-interpreting the guidelines (which themselves, being just a short summary and not an exhaustive explanation of all of the intricacies of editing).  You cannot just edit your own original content into another person's post.  This is a long established principle of editing on the site.

Comment: @Shane If you make edits like this they're going to get rejected by review.  If they get applied they're going to get rolled back.  If you continue to make them anyway a mod will be forced to step in and *stop* you from making such edits, and if you continue to exhibit such behavior, further action may need to be taken.  The fact that you *want* to be able to edit whatever you want into anyone else's posts doesn't make it appropriate.

Comment: @Servy WOW. Is it possible for you to make a point without resorting to strawmen? No, I don't think " that all of the editing guidelines posted in the help center mean nothing at all". I think that these edit followed the guidelines *to the letter*.  CarpetSmoker saw all the comments from siannopollo, tinybyte, user706420, and Weboide that added useful information. Then he read the editting guidelines that says: ***To include additional information only found in comments, so all of the information relevant to the post is contained in one place***. Then he did *exactly* that.

Comment: @Servy You are arguing that who wrote something, ownership of the answer, is more important than having the best answer possible. That is so wrong. AGAIN:  "Our goal is to have the best answers to every question, so if you see questions or answers that can be improved, you can edit them." Where and WHO the information came from is not part of the criteria. This is written again and again in plain black and white.

Comment: @Shane It's not a strawman.  You specifically said, "The only thing that matters is whether or not the edits improve the question".You have specifically contradicted the editing guidelines.  You're taking a specific line out of context, and interpreting it as meaning that all edits are okay no matter what they change, which simply isn't the case.

Comment: @Shane `You are arguing that who wrote something, ownership of the answer, is more important than having the best answer possible.` That's a false dichotomy.  The way that SO provides the best answer is by letting each individual user post what they think the best answer is, and having the best answer rise through the top through voting.  The fact that posts can be edited, and there are certain context in which it's appropriate to improve a post through editing in no way implies that you can edit whatever you want about any post.

Comment: @Shane  `This is written again and again in plain black and white.`  It's written in plain, black and white statements, that you are not supposed to be editing other people's posts to add your own original content, and yet you seem to just be ignoring this entirely and pretending that it doesn't exist.

Comment: @Shane Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96217/discussion-on-answer-by-servy-how-to-handle-significant-changes-to-my-answer).

Answer (score -1):

The way I handled it in the end was to have the editor post an a different answer and I linked to it.

[Delete with Join in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/652770/delete-with-join-in-mysql/29204958#29204958)

I think the shorter answer is better for most people so I prefer to leave it as it.  But if people want more detail I'm happy that someone else consolidated it.